# Is .OfType<dynamicType> possible?

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to do something like this psuedocode....

```
//COMPANYTYPES = ENUM
FOR EACH (COMPANY TYPE IN COMPANYTYPES)
{
        var result = companies.OfType<type>().
}
```

However I can't find a way to make  not angry. Is it possible to do this? Or does the type need to be hardcoded in at compile time?

edit: I marked an anwser below, but thought I would show my complete WORKING code as well in case its helpful to anyone else:

```
foreach (CompanyType companyType in Enum.GetValues(typeof (CompanyType)))
        {
            var temp = GetTypeFromCompanyEnum(companyType);

            foreach (var company in companies.Where(temp.IsInstanceOfType))
            {
                //code here
            }
        }
```

Comment: We have no idea what you mean by "FOR EACH (COMPANY TYPE IN COMPANYTYPES)" If `CompanyTypes` is an enum, then it's a type *in itself*. If you could give a short but complete example, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that `type` is of type `Type`.

You cannot do that using generics; generics are all about *compile-time* types.

Instead, you can call `.Where(type.IsInstanceOfType)`.
Note that this will also match instances of subtypes.